# Duda con los Links Dinámicos en Flutter y Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

estoy intentando crear una aplicacion y quiero generar links con invitaciones para compartirlos por whats app. La idea es que el usuario haga click en el link y le lleva a la aplicacion si esta instalada y si no a la app store.

Para ello estoy utlizando los "Dynamic links" de Firebase. El problema es que no sabria la forma de generar un link único para cada invitacion con FireBase. Por ello tambien he investigado y he visto que estos links se pueden programar en el propio flutter, por ejemplo de la siguiente forma en este ejemplo sacado de Fiddle Stacks:

```
Future<String> createFirstPostLink(String title) async {
    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: 'https://filledstacks.page.link',
      link: Uri.parse('https://www.compound.com/post?title=$title'),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'com.filledstacks.compound',
      ),
      // NOT ALL ARE REQUIRED ===== HERE AS AN EXAMPLE =====
      iosParameters: IosParameters(
        bundleId: 'com.example.ios',
        minimumVersion: '1.0.1',
        appStoreId: '123456789',
      ),
      googleAnalyticsParameters: GoogleAnalyticsParameters(
        campaign: 'example-promo',
        medium: 'social',
        source: 'orkut',
      ),
      itunesConnectAnalyticsParameters: ItunesConnectAnalyticsParameters(
        providerToken: '123456',
        campaignToken: 'example-promo',
      ),
      socialMetaTagParameters: SocialMetaTagParameters(
        title: 'Example of a Dynamic Link',
        description: 'This link works whether app is installed or not!',
      ),
    );

    final Uri dynamicUrl = await parameters.buildUrl();

    return dynamicUrl.toString();
}
```

La pregunta es como podría adaptar eso para mi caso teniendo en cuenta que mi api tiene la siguente forma:

[http://app.aplicacion.com/api/[APIKEYU]/{id_invitación}](http://app.aplicacion.com/api/%5BAPIKEYU%5D/%7Bid_invitaci%C3%B3n%7D)

y el formato de FireBase es http://aplicacion.page.link

Ante todo sabed que soy muy nuevo en esto y no se muy bien por donde tirar. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como lo indica tu ejemplo, una vez que tienes configurado Dynamic Link en tu proyecto, para generar un link dinámico solo necesitas pasarle los parámetros de acuerdo a tu configuración:

```dart
final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: 'http://aplicacion.page.link',
      link: Uri.parse('https://www.compound.com/post?title=$title'),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'package_name_de_tu_app_android',
      ),
      iosParameters: IosParameters(
        bundleId: 'com.example.ios',
        appStoreId: '123456789',
      ),
      socialMetaTagParameters: SocialMetaTagParameters(
        title: 'Example of a Dynamic Link',
        description: 'This link works whether app is installed or not!',
      ),
    );
```

El `package_name_de_tu_app_android` lo sacas del `build.gradle` dentro de `android/app`.

El `bundleId` es el bundle identifier de iOS, si entras a XCode lo puedes ver o en todo caso buscando esta palabra `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` en tu proyecto lo encontrarás.

El `appStoreId` es el id que tiene en el appstore, en iTunnesConnect podrías ver que número le asignaron luego de crear tu app.

En `link` le envías el link que quieres capturar desde tu app, ese link recibirás y podrás parsearlo para obtener los parámetros. En tu caso podría ser: `Uri.parse('http://app.aplicacion.com/api/[APIKEYU]/{id_invitación}')`

Para `uriPrefix` si necesitas pasarle el page link que tienes `http://aplicacion.page.link` .

NOTA: no te olvides de configurar bien dynamic link siguiendo las instrucciones del plugin.